# Logged linear regression, Add a trendline to a scatter plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, linear-regression

I have a linear regression model that has root mass as y and aboveground tree mass as x.

> `model2<-lm(log(root_total)~log(abv_total),data=Li2003hardwood)`

I would like to add a trendline for this model using ggplot but I don't know how to specify the model I used. I know formula=y~log(x) is not correct its just there as a place holder.

Also I am just trying to recreate a plot from a old publication (Belowground biomass dynamics in the Carbon Budget Model of the Canadian Forest Sector) with the original data. Trying to understand how to add the trendline that follows the logged data but keep the axis unlogged as they did in the publication.

```
ggplot(data=Li2003hardwood,aes(x=abv_total,y=root_total))+
    geom_point()+
    geom_smooth(method="lm",formula=y~log(x),se=FALSE,color="black")
```

Comment: can you post an image of the original plot? (is it this? https://cdnsciencepub.com/doi/10.1139/x02-165 )

Comment: Hi Ben, I would have posted a image of the original plot but I was unable to as I am a newer user and don't have that privilege yet. I was able to solve my issue though. Thanks for leaving a comment, much appreciated.

Comment: Please share a reproducible dataset using the `dput` function. Here is how: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Answer (score 2):

I was able to figure out how to add the trend line.

```
plot(root_total~abv_total,data=Li2003hardwood)

curve(exp(predict(model2, 
    newdata = data.frame(abv_total = x))), col = "black", add = TRUE)
```